# UL Child Nodes Different Lengths

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
<ul id="meganFox">
    <li>Frank</li>
    <li>Jeff</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
</ul>
<div id="debug"></div>
<script language="javascript">
var nodes = document.getElementById('meganFox').childNodes;
var el = document.getElementById('debug');
for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ){
    el.innerHTML += i +' - '+ nodes[i] +'<br />';
}
alert( nodes.length );
</script>
```

> Firefox alert:  7 
>   0 - [object Text]
>
> 1 - [object HTMLLIElement]
>
> 2 - [object Text]
>
> 3 - [object HTMLLIElement]
>
> 4 - [object Text]
>
> 5 - [object HTMLLIElement]
>
> 6 - [object Text]
>
> IE alert: 3
>
> 0 - [object]
>
> 1 - [object]
>
> 2 - [object]

Why is it 7?  What is object text versus just object?

My end goal is to capture the key event and navigate through it with the up and down arrows.  I got it working properly in IE, but it isn't working in FF because of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W3 compliant browsers consider whitespace between elements to be part of the DOM (text nodes).

Older versions of IE don't. That's why you get 3 in IE, vs 7 elsewhere.

The `[object]` output is just apparently what IE's `toString()` of element nodes gives.

If you don't want any text nodes, then do this in your `for` loop...

```
for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ){
    if( nodes[i].nodeType === 3 )
        continue;
    else
        el.innerHTML += i +' - '+ nodes[i] +'<br />';
}
```

This will eliminate all text nodes (not just empty ones). To preserve non-empty nodes, you can do this...

```
for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ){
    if( nodes[i].nodeType === 3 && !nodes[i].data.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '') )
        continue;
    else
        el.innerHTML += i +' - '+ nodes[i] +'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I'm using IE8 and IE9, so they're not old versions of IE.  I'm trying to figure out the definition of an "empty text node" still.  Googling it.

Comment: Oh wow, I figured out that it is just the white space in the code...  I hate FF.  :P  Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @phpmeh: Sorry, I should have said whitespace only between the elements. That includes spaces, line breaks, and tabs. I consider IE8 to be an old version. I though IE9 had that fixed.